# How to increase wubi /root disk space

Tags: wubi, resize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I give Ubuntu 10.10 more space (when installed inside Windows 7 (via wubi))?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35401/how-do-i-give-ubuntu-10-10-more-space-when-installed-inside-windows-7-via-wubi)

I'm running out of space in wubi. Online wubi help didn't help much since they suggest creating extra virtual disk space(similar to having a diffrent partition i guess) . None of them speak about increasing the size of /root disk space(or root.disk). I store all files in space shared with windows or external disk and use ubuntu only to install and use softwares and browsing. 
So how do increase the available space for installing more softwares?

Comment: The wubi guide has a section on this (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) - or refer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/35401/how-do-i-give-ubuntu-10-10-more-space-when-installed-inside-windows-7-via-wubi