# /dev/loop0 doesn't have enough disk space

Tags: partitioning, wubi

I have too little space in my /dev/loop0 :

```
/dev/loop0 5,6G 5,1G 170M 97% /
none 3,0G 268K 3,0G 1% /dev
none 3,0G 1,5M 3,0G 1% /dev/shm
none 3,0G 144K 3,0G 1% /var/run
none 3,0G 0 3,0G 0% /var/lock
/dev/sda5 16G 9,5G 6,2G 61% /host
/dev/sdb1 373G 373G 130M 100% /media/disco externo-1
```

How can I expand the space for /dev/loop0?  Basically, the system is always warning about lack of space.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have installed through WUBI, so you can try this solution: [How to increase wubi /root disk space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23198/how-to-increase-wubi-root-disk-space)