# How do I give Ubuntu more space (when installed inside Windows 7 (via wubi))?

Tags: wubi, disk-management

**I had installed Ubuntu inside Windows XP but then I formatted XP and installed Windows 7.**

EDIT1: I used Wubi for the same.
I want to know which one of the two will solve my problem? creating a virtual disk or resizing root? Also is resizing root possible as the 4GB ext4 partition is already in a NTFS format Hard Drive partition.

At the time of installation I had allocated only 4GB of space to Ubuntu. I want to increase that size as I keep getting a low disk space notification.

*I have surfed through a lot of similar questions but this is not a duplicate.*

**Because I want to know a little about the file systems. In order to solve my problem,do I have to increase the size of root.disk? Or will it be solved by creating a virtual disk?**

Also I want to know the difference between creating a virtual disk and just increasing disk space of root.I'm new to Ubuntu so I don't know how the file systems function.

EDIT2:I have created a virtual disk of 10gb ,but I'm still getting the same notification.Is there anyway to install all further applications on the virtual disk I created?

Comment: When you say you installed Ubuntu "inside" Windows XP, what exactly do you mean? If you don't know the technical term for it, can you link to a web page that shows how you did it?

Comment: @Robin - Please check EDIT1

Comment: @Robin: Its a Wubi install, that's how you get it inside Windows normally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Additional virtual disks are only useful if you're able to split the filesystem (eg putting `/home/` on it) so aren't much use if you've installed a ton of stuff. You *can* split things like `/usr/bin` but it can get really messy, really fast.

Have you not seen a link to [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10590851&postcount=2) on your travels? You'll need a LiveCD or LiveUSB to action it, but it's very simple once you're at that point. Here are the main points:

- `mount` your windows partition (where the Wubi install sits)
- `fsck` the Wubi filesystem to make sure it's okay. If you don't do this and it has corruption in it before resizing, bad things can happen.
- `resize2fs` the Wubi filesystem to increase its size.
- Have a snack, chill out, high-five yourself... You've just increased the partition size.

Those aren't the full commands, I'll leave those in [that thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10590851&postcount=2) because it seems to be well maintained.

Failing that, installing Ubuntu only takes a few minutes. If you like it, perhaps you should consider a proper install (disk performance is better too).

Comment: The thread you linked to has been closed, but now the Wubi resize methods are documented in the Wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeWubiDisk and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell here whether you are referring to [virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization) or simply [the Wubi installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/windows-installer).

Assuming the former, first increase the size of the virtual disk, since that will allow us to expand the actual partition.

Then mount the LiveCD in the Virtual Machine and run `gparted`. Using that tool, resize the partition to take up the remaining space you created when you expanded the disk. Now reboot and unmount the CD.

Comment: Apparently he means Wubi (see the update he made), so you will have to update your answer :(.

Comment: @Roland: I don't know anything about Wubi... so I can't :P

Comment: I have created a virtual disk,but I'm still getting the same notification.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't have to boot from a livecd to do this:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero bs=1MiB of=/host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk conv=notrunc oflag=append count=2048
sudo losetup -c /dev/loop0
sudo resize2fs /dev/loop0
```

This will add 2 GiB to the filesystem.  Adjust the count=2048 for different sizes.

Comment: first command says 
2048+0 records in
2048+0 records out
2147483648 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 48.1784 s, 44.6 MB/s
Second command says
loop: can't set capacity on device /dev/loop0/: Not a directory
and third one 
The filesystem is already 2494464 blocks long.  Nothing to do!

but not added any where

Comment: @shailesh, woops!  I put an extra slash on the end there, it's just /dev/loop0

Comment: Thnaks for reply. I found a very easy way to extends root.disk.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk
JUST extract zip from link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=wubi-resize-1.7.tar.gz
and run the command one line and this will done all jobs within minuts.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is too late but helpful for new comer

Install 14.04 Ubuntu via WUBI in windows 8. I have done these steps:

Download the iso from Ubuntu site.
mount it in a virtual drive in windows and copy all files in a drives folder.
From the folder click the exe to run WUBI setup. Which runs same as 10.x Ubuntu.

In 5 to 10 min it ask to restart, I have a issue of ro (read only) so convert it to rw(read and write) as show here [Describe Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-tmp-could-not-be-mounted)

**Above part is for installing..**

***To extend the WUBI root.disk is a way.***

I have found solution [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk)
you need to download a zip from link [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=wubi-resize-1.7.tar.gz).

Extract it and just run the one line command and this will done all job

```
sudo bash wubi-resize.sh 10
```

Above commad will done following job:

Create a disk(Virtual) with desired (10GB) size in drive. 
Copy all data from you running disk to newly created disk
and ask you to boot Windows and rename root.disk to OLDroot.disk and new.disk (New drive)
to root.disk and reboot again Ubuntu. Now check you system propery it will show your new size.
This works well for me.

Thanks