# How to increase the partition size of Ubuntu installed under Windows?

Tags: wubi, resize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I give Ubuntu 10.10 more space (when installed inside Windows 7 (via wubi))?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35401/how-do-i-give-ubuntu-10-10-more-space-when-installed-inside-windows-7-via-wubi)

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 under Windows (using Wubi) and the default size for the "partition" was chosen as 10GB. Now it shows frequent issues due to low disk space. How can I increase the size of partition without reinstalling?

Answer (score 4):

As [Marky](https://askubuntu.com/users/4216/marky) suggested in the [comments](https://askubuntu.com/q/45229/22949), you can resize the disk image of a Wubi installation using any of [these methods](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1625371&highlight=resize2fs%20wubi) (written by [bcbc](https://askubuntu.com/users/14916/bcbc)).

Alternatively, you can free up space in your Wubi image by moving some of your documents or other files like music, ebooks, or videos (just not programs or system files) to the host Windows system's partition (accessed as `/host` in your Wubi system).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can if it is a Wubi install.

However a remarkably easy and very effective fix (other than starting from scratch, making a new partition and installing Ubuntu there) is to follow the instructions and use the script in **[HOWTO: migrate wubi install to partition](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1519354)** in Ubuntu forums.

I am a relative non-expert but I had this done in less than an hour (more like 30 mins) and it was perfect. It has the additional advantage that the Wubi (Windows) install remains intact just in case you have a problem with the migration and, of course, you will be able to change the new partition size if you need to later.

Comment: It is possible and easy. There is another tip made by the same poster 'bcbc' on the ubuntu forums (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1625371&highlight=resize2fs+wubi), particularly the one using resize2fs instead of the script. I was done in 10 minutes or less. Make sure you go to the 'In place Resize of root.disk' part of resizing the disk.

Comment: I remember that post now. Frankly my brain phased out when I looked at the instructions and I came back the next day and just did the migrate. Glad I did. Hardly openned Windows since.