# How to make Ubuntu use the entire partition?

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

I have a partition for Windows (sda2) and one for Ubuntu (sda3). I've installed Ubuntu from Windows with the Windows Ubuntu installer (Wubi) and set an installation size of 13GB (I guess).

[image]

Everything works fine, but I'm running out of disk space, even though there should be enough left. Here's what **GParted** says:

[image]

And this is what **Ubuntu** tells me (and actually believes):

[image: filesystem screenshot]

So it seems that Ubuntu only uses the space defined as the installation size in Wubi. Why is that (since I assumed that "installation size" just affected the amount of packages and extra stuff installed) and how can I make Ubuntu use the entire partition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increase the partition size of Ubuntu installed under Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/45158/how-to-increase-the-partition-size-of-ubuntu-installed-under-windows)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: this question is a little different, because as you can see he was confused as to how it works in the first place and has a separate partition :)

Comment: Yes, wubi can be confusing for both new and veteran users. I rely on bcbc ;)

Comment: @RolandTaylor & bodhi.zazen: I'guess I'm in trouble now...  you're actually both right and helped me a lot, and I'd like to accept both answers. Please don't take it personally, I'm marking bodhi.zazen's post as the answer because it might be more helpful for the ones with the same problem who do not want to do a fresh install.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally support using wubi (as an alternate to virtualization) to determine if you like Ubuntu and if it works on your hardware. Personally my advice is that if you like ubuntu I would advise you do a "standard" installation, you are half way there, you have already partitioned your hard drive.

At any rate, your problem is with the default size of the wubi virtual disk. Wubi loop mounts a file and you have to increase the file size.

See the [most excellent post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1625371) by bcbc on the Ubuntu forms for a walk through. Only you can decide if it is easier to maintain / resize your wubi install or start fresh.

Comment: Is wubi dead now? I was under the impression that support was dropped for it. https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2015-August/015792.html

Comment: @ElderGeek Probably is dead although there are probably some die hard supporters. Keep in mind this question / answer is almost 5 years old now.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the age of the post.

Comment: @ElderGeek - If you are interested post on the mailing list or contact members of the Wubi team. Last I heard they were active and patches were available the issue was neither Canonical nor the community wanted to maintain packages or a live disk. Support is limited.

Comment: See http://wubi.sourceforge.net/faq.php#development and https://code.launchpad.net/wubi/ . Code was last submitted in 2016 so it appears the project is still active.

Answer (score 3):

It is a little difficult to understand your question, but I'll try to help you make some sense of the situation and hopefully that will help you to get an answer.

The "installation size" is how big the virtual disk Ubuntu uses will be. So essentially you gave it a 17GB ".disk" file.

It appears you are confusing the wubi install with a real installation (which would have installed Ubuntu on the partition you have labeled as Linux). In order to install Linux on that partition, you actually need to boot Ubuntu from the livecd/usb and not use the "wubi" installer (which installs inside of windows).

As for why you are only seeing 939.9MB free, I'm not 100% sure from the details you have given.

Comment: Thank you very much, this actually makes sense now :) I thought Wubi was just as good as a real installation... Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Quasdunk: you're welcome!
If this answer answered your question, you can mark it as answered by clicking the tick next to it (don't if it didn't lol).