# How to add more space to my ubuntu 10.04 installation

Tags: wubi, gparted, disk-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Ubuntu use the entire partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94373/how-to-make-ubuntu-use-the-entire-partition)

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 on my 64 bit machine using Wubi.Both windows and Ubuntu are installed on the C drive. I have the D drive which as over 40GB free. Now I want to give that free space to my Ubuntu.

I read that I can do it with Gparted but I am not sure how to.

So can someone please explain this process step by step?

Looking forward to your positive response.

Cheers.
Jayneil.
(jayneil.dalal@gmail.com)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to expand the linux partition ? Can you install and use the palimpsest utility ?
Also you can do this with gparted just expand your partition. (not the small swap partition!)