# Change  size of root partition after installing Ubuntu in Windows

Tags: partitioning, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increase size of root partition after installing Ubuntu in Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118300/increase-size-of-root-partition-after-installing-ubuntu-in-windows)

I recently installed Ubuntu via the windows installer with 10 GB and wish to increase the size to 20 GB. Is there a way to do so with out reinstalling Ubuntu via windows?

Comment: me too, I think it's dangerous though.