# How do I resize a Wubi partition (Ubuntu installed by Windows)?

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increase size of root partition after installing Ubuntu in Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118300/increase-size-of-root-partition-after-installing-ubuntu-in-windows)

I wanted to add more space to the Ubuntu partition, but only two partitions appear, `/dev/sda1` is 100mb of what i assume is boot data, and `/dev/sda2` is the `/host` directory, which has all the Windows files on it. I suspect Ubuntu is running in the Windows files somewhere.

I have had Banshee and Skype both error messaging, and I have been unable to install anything without removing files, so clearly the issue is urgent.
All I want is to allocate about 30GB of space to Ubuntu.

Any help much appreciated.