# Resizing partitioned windows7/ubuntu12.04

Tags: resize

I have a windows7 600GB HD that I partitioned to 350GB for windows7 and 250GB for ubuntu, but after some times I started getting messages that my HD is running out of space whenever I used the ubuntu os. Then I realized the ubuntu os is installed in a space of 17GB which I don't know how it came about. My question is how to resize the the 17GB so that I can have the ubuntu os in the 250GB.

I am new in ubuntu and need help desperately cos I don't wanna loose my work there....

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest downloading Gparted  and creating a boot disk.  This will give you a simple method of creating, deleting and resizing disk partitions.  The following links may help:

[Gnome Partition Editor](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/index.php)

[GParted partitioning software – Full tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html)

[Manual partitioning](http://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/manual-partitioning/)

In addition, since you are concerned about maintaining the integrity of your system/data, if you don't already make regular backups, I would suggest that you do so prior to changing the disk structure.

Comment: I think you can also run GParted from a live cd

Answer (score 0):

From the size it sounds like you did a Wubi install inside the Windows partition, not a a full install in another partition.  Have a look at this question which asks how to resize a Wubi install. : [increase-size-of-root-partition-after-installing-ubuntu-in-windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118300/)

It might be better to install properly on that spare partition rather than continue to use Wubi when you don't need to.  You'll need to boot off the Live CD or USB to install Ubuntu but before you do boot the Ubuntu that you have installed and check which disk the root file system is on.  As per the question linked above, open a terminal window after Ubuntu boots and type the following:

```
df -h
```

and paste the results here so we can see.

From the result of you 'df -h' you can see that Ubuntu is running off an 18GB Virtual disk that is in the Windows partition.  In other words, you did a Wubi install, you did not set up a dual boot system with Ubuntu in its own partition.

I suggest you boot off the LiveCD or LiveUSB and do a full install of Ubuntu alongside Windows.

I highly recommend that you back up all your important data before you do this.  While it's unlikely anything bad will happen if you are very careful, it's good piece of mind to know that your data is safe if something bad does happen.  Chris

Comment: Here is what I have after typing df -h    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       18G   16G  967M  95% /
udev            2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           795M  920K  794M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G  800K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda2       383G  178G  205G  47% /host
grub-mount       18G   16G  967M  95% /var/lib/os-prober/mount
/dev/sda5       100M   18M   82M  19% /media/HP_TOOLS

Comment: Here is a screenshot file:///home/juila/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202012-10-05%2008:12:11.png