# Installer doesn't recognise windows 7 install

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-7

I will start off saying I searched a bit for this problem with little success. You see, I am an utmost noob when it comes to Ubuntu and Linux based OS (hence why I want to install it and discover it) and the thread I found were too specific for me to do anything with. Therefore, if you find a thread that is noob-friendly and answers my question, please link it below or please try to answer as simply as possible :)
The problem: I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit alongside Windows 7 on my main hard drive (to get the choice which one to start when booting). Pop the CD in, reboot and get to the installer screen. I know I'm supposed to have 3 options, but I'm only given the option to erase my hard drive or "do something else".
Therefore, my question is: how do I make Ubuntu recognise Windows 7, so it may install alongside it?

Comment: Do you have secure boot option in BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a full tutorial on how to resize a partition using the "Something else" option here: [Resizing partitioned windows7/ubuntu12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196735/resizing-partitioned-windows7-ubuntu12-04)