# Not enough space left in the hard drive. How to proceed?

Tags: 12.04, downloads, disk-usage

Where do I begin... I can hardly do anything on Ubuntu 12.04. I am very close to removing and returning to Windows. First I could not load it because the graphics appeared to be running low but somehow that stopped happening and I could log on.
Now I can not download anything or I get this message

> Cannot write: No space left on device.

I tried trouble shooting this issue but every time I try and fix the problem I am blocked by this message

```
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: Can't mmap an empty file
E: Failed to truncate file - ftruncate (9: Bad file descriptor)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
$ OLD=$(ls -tr /boot/vmlinuz-* | head -n -2 | cut -d- -f2- | awk '{print "linux-image-" $0}')
```

Ubuntu is also running incredibly slow and I cant get anything done! Please help this is driving me mad!

Comment: Clearly, you are running out of space. Try adding more storage to the Ubuntu partition?

Comment: Try booting from a Ubuntu Live CD and deleting unnecessary files from there.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the output of `df`.

Comment: Can you add the outcome of `sudo fdisk -l`?

Answer (score 3):

I think, you have downloaded too much software in your Ubuntu. I suggest you to copy all of those packages in other partition of the disk or in a USB drive or DVD. Then  use this command

```
 sudo apt-get clean
```

to clear the package cache. It will quickly give you some more space

As you are using Wubi to install Ubuntu, You may try these solution posted here:

- [How to increase the partition size of Ubuntu installed under Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/q/45158/61218)
- [Increase size of  Wubi partition](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=777797)
- [Resize and duplicate Wubi partition (recommended)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk)

Or you may try to move the Wubi installation to a larger partition with regular installation

- [Migrate Wubi to a regular installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi)

Comment: I have plenty of hard drive space Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       17G   17G     0 100% /
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           772M  976K  771M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  276K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda2       445G  103G  342G  24% /host
/dev/sdc10      932G   82G  850G   9% /media/My Passport for Mac
/dev/sdb1       466G  436G   30G  94% /media/FreeAgent GoFlex Drive      So do I need to still tranfer any files to usb etc. And if I need to partition which is the best and safest way

Comment: @jimbobjgr Are you using Ubuntu from Live CD? Anyway, having enough hard drive space doesn't matter here. Because Ubuntu uses it's own partition, not the entire hard drive

Comment: I am not using from a cd I used the windows download wizard thingy. I think it must be something to do with the partition, but I am having difficulty getting my head around how it works and how I can fix it.

Comment: @jimbobjgr Then you are stuck I think. You must extend the file which is holding the Ubuntu partition inside your windows partition. I'll try to update the answer with a solution, if I find one. Most probably, you may need to install Ubuntu again with larger space.

Comment: ok, how has this happened? Surely when Ubuntu is installed it should automatically install with the right amount of space to function?

Comment: @jimbobjgr I think, you downloaded huge amount to software and installed them. Also note, Wubi can't  automatically know how much software you would install. You have to select the size during installation

Comment: right but if I have an external hard drive and have been putting everything on it, shouldnt that have freed up the memory?

Comment: It should free up the disc space a bit. But it really depends on the actual size of the disc. If you are happy with the solution, go for it.

Comment: I mean thats what I have been doing . There shouldnt be much on my main memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the cache using

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
```

Comment: better yet, `sudo apt-get clean`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have decided to get rid of Ubuntu. It has created far to many hours of work and Ii hadnt any time to do any of my own work... I hope to see it improve and perhaps one day I will use it again as I like the Idea.