# How to increase the space in ubuntu installed under windows7?

Tags: partitioning, wubi

I have windows7 running on my PC which has only one partition(C:).
I have installed ubuntu to make it a dual boot. After i installed few applications,i get and error saying no enough free space left. 
Can someone help me in finding out how to increase the memory without re-installing/ losing the data.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you meant to say that you have installed it using wubi, because as you have said you have only one partition, and hence it is not possible to have dual boot. For increasing size under wubi, see this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/45158/58990

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to extend the disk space available to a wubi install?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2465/is-it-possible-to-extend-the-disk-space-available-to-a-wubi-install)

Comment: Maybe you can use Gparted partition edition manager..
or you can login in to windows and shrink the volume in windows partition and add it to unallocated space.

Answer (score 3):

First download the attached file [wubi-resize-1.6.tar.gz](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=wubi-resize-1.6.tar.gz) to your Downloads directory, right-click and choose "Extract here". The rest of the resize is run from the Terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open).

```
cd ~/Downloads/wubi-resize-1.6

bash wubi-resize.sh --help

sudo bash wubi-resize.sh <your desired space in GB>
```

This will resize wubi as per you want.

Answer (score 0):

In case it tells you that you cannot increase the size more than 32 GB:

```
$ sudo bash wubi-resize_1.5b.sh 80
wubi-resize_1.5b.sh: The new disk cannot exceed 32 GB unless the
wubi-resize_1.5b.sh: --max-override option is used (not recommended).
```

Feel free to run it with `--max-override` option. I increased my root disk file to 100GB from 30GB. It worked perfectly. wubi-resize makes a new root disk (new.dsk) copies all the files in it from current root disk to it and then asks you to go to windows and rename root.dsk to OLDroot.dsk and new.dsk to root.dsk and restart. This way your old root disk remains saved until you are satisfied that new is working fine and you can delete the old one then. This process does take long though, I ran sudo bash wubi-resize_1.5b.sh --max-override 100 overnight and it was done when I woke up in the morning, so don't know the exact time.