# How to increase size of primary partition?

Tags: wubi, filesystem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)
>   [How do I give Ubuntu 10.10 more space (when installed inside Windows 7 (via wubi))?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35401/how-do-i-give-ubuntu-10-10-more-space-when-installed-inside-windows-7-via-wubi)

I have installed Ubuntu from Windows 8 using windows installer on a small allocated space same partition as windows. Now I want to use ubuntu as my primary OS so want to allocate it more space. Can I do that without loosing windows or linux data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [this file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=wubi-resize-1.6.tar.gz) Now from your terminal do following. For example we want to make it 20 GB then:

```
cd ~/Downloads/wubi-resize-1.6
sudo bash wubi-resize.sh 20
```

Reference:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk
```

Comment: I use mint and thought what works for ubuntu will work for mint but unfortunately it does not :( Thank you for answer