# Would executing fsck and resize2fs be possible in Cygwin?

Tags: wubi, fsck

I want to increase my Wubi Ubuntu installation size and I found a blog [here](http://linuxnick.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-increase-size-of-your-existing.html) which has some directions for doing so. I don't have a Ubuntu bootable disc. Can anyone tell if the same things can be done by using Cygwin in Windows?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: you did not read the comments in that blog post?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I did now. And so I changed the scope of my question.

Comment: Theoretically, yes, but you may find this answer more useful: http://askubuntu.com/a/443786/8500