# How expand ubuntu partition in dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

So, I have dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04.1 and windows 7, and I partitioned 150gb from my HDD to Ubuntu and initially while installing Ubuntu through wubi it asked me to allocate space to Ubuntu and I went with  the default option of 20gb. Now after installing several software and apps Ubuntu is telling me I am running out of space (0.0mb/20.0gb available) when I clearly installed it on the 150gb disk, I think I should have have selected 100gb or more while installing initially but now I am confused, is there a way I can expand my ubuntu partition to take the complete 150gb of the disk.

Maybe these Images will help:

[Of 155gb 20gb used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFwN4.png)

[showing 3gb available of 20gb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B6sK.png)

Disclaimer: I don't have a usb or an optical drive
Please Help!
Thank You!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! how did you install ubuntu if you don't have a usb drive? the easiest way to do what you want is to boot a live usb and use gparted to edit the partitions.

Comment: Did you actually install using wubi? It has a maximum space of 20GB. And wubi was last supported with 12.04, although available in some of the newer versions. Better to get flash drive or DVD and do a full install.

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte As I said, I installed it via Wubi, i don't have a usb drive currently. oh, and thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: @oldfred So you're saying I'm screwed, Do I have to uninstall it completely and reinstall it via usb drive? And wubi did give me options to select the space upto 100gb and it was available for 18.04.1. btw thank you for replying

Comment: my bad, I see that now... you're going to have to figure out how to do it from windows, which unfortunately is out of scope here. this might help: https://www.disk-partition.com/tutorials/resize-partition-win-7-free.html

Comment: Get several flash drives. You should have a Windows repair flash drive, your Ubuntu live install and perhaps more for various backups. Ubuntu does not install to NTFS formatted partitions, so it is wubi which is just a file inside an NTFS partition. Back up any data you want to save, /home particularlly and export list of installed apps to make it easy to reinstall. I do not see an extended partition if MBR, or is it gpt partitioned? Or is drive converted to Windows proprietary dynamic partitions which does not work with Linux. Post this: `sudo fdisk -lu`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give Ubuntu more space (when installed inside Windows 7 (via wubi))?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35401/386067)